# SoftLayer API and IPv6 subnets

Tags: ipv6, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there any way to find the hosts in a given IPv6 subnet using the SoftLayer API? Calling the `.getHardware()` method on an IPv6 subnet object always returns an empty list; there also seem to be no attributes or methods on individual Hardware objects to get the associated IPv6 address.

*Note: I've tried asking this upstream and was specifically asked to post on Stack Overflow*

Answer (score 0):

Try the following REST request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet/652260/getIpAddresses
```

Method: Get

Replace: $user, $apiKey with your own information. Replace **652261** with the IPv6 subnet identifier.

References:

- [SoftLayer_Network_Subnet::getIpAddresses](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet/getIpAddresses)

Comment: Yeah, I get it  -- the `hardware` mask on an IPv6 subnet is always empty, but the `hardware` mask on the associated SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress isn't.

Comment: A raw query of `https://$SL_USERNAME_ENCODED:$SL_API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet/$SUBNET_ID/?objectMask=ipAddresses.hardware.fullyQualifiedDomainName;ipAddresses.ipAddress` Seems to work fine.

Comment: Yep, you are right. It seems an issue that [SoftLayer_Network_Subnet::getHardware](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet/getHardware) method doesn't return hardware objects attached to their ip addresses.